# How to filter users on custom meta fields in WP JSON v2?

Tags: rest-api, wp-api

I am trying to filter users on meta field, say abc is user meta field and value is 123 for user1.

I have tried filter parameter with WP query like parameters, but it returns all users. 'search' parameter only filter on username

Comment: Did you find a way to solve it? I'm having a similar problem.